# Liferay deployment in linux Server

Tags: liferay

i have installed liferay 7 in linux server. but when i try start the server it doesnt start properly shows up without css .[image]

Is there any procedure to install liferay in linux server

Browser Console

[image]

Some files are accessing with url localhost

```
http://localhost:8383/o/classic-theme/css/aui.css?browserId=firefox&themeId=classic_WAR_classictheme&minifierType=css&languageId=en_US&b=7002&t=32

http://localhost:8383/o/mentions-web/css/mentions.css

/o url is not generating with hostname instead generates with localhost
```

Comment: There might be issues with the path of css files. What does the browser console says?

Comment: i have added browser console yes its issue of path @ParkashKumar

Comment: The issue might be reproducible using domain name, right?

Comment: From the snapshot, it is not obvious that from these files have being loaded. Can you highlight some of the resources URLs?

Comment: i have added the generated url

Comment: This has most probably nothing to do with Linux. I'd guess that you point at the wrong track. Interesting thing is the difference between the requested server and the generated URLs for CSS. But you don't include the important information: What is your setup? Do you have any proxy or loadbalancer between the browser and the Liferay-Server? Which servlet container are you using? Tomcat? ...

Comment: it worked by adding web.server.host=domainname
web.server.http.port=80 in portal-ext.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason i added

```
web.server.host=domain
web.server.http.port=80
```

in

```
portal-ext.properties
```

[image]

It works now. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score -2):

After setting up the username password and db details kindly go to the page settings and try to change the theme or check their the option for csss.

or 
add this property in portal-ext.properties file present in the tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes or you need to create portal-ext.properties file.

> ```
> theme.css.fast.load=true
> ```

Comment: i ll try this one

Comment: i have create properties file and if i could add host name to ..server is running nginx